# mysql Create named table from values in select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, `System`, with a bunch of fields including `System.serial`.
I have a list of serial numbers that I want to get the status of.

Simple enough:

```
Select * from System where System.serial in ('s1','s2', 'sn');
```

However the list of serial numbers also has serials NOT IN the `System` table.
Obviously they are not in the results.

I want the missing serials to show in the results also but with no data.

The best way I can think of doing this is to make a temporary table with one column, `serial`, and then left join `System` on it.

How can I do this **without** creating a temporary table?

Something like:

```
Select listOfSerials.serial, System.* 
from (Select ('s1','s2', 'sn') as serial ) as ListOfSerials 
left join System on System.serial = ListOfSerials.serial;
```

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with your solution of creating a virtual table with which to do LEFT JOIN against your real data.

You can create a derived table as a series of UNIONed SELECT statements that select literal values with no table reference.

```
SELECT listOfSerials.serial, System.* 
FROM (
    SELECT 's1' AS serial
    UNION SELECT 's2'
    UNION SELECT 'sn'
) AS ListOfSerials 
LEFT JOIN System ON System.serial = ListOfSerials.serial;
```

You only need to define a column alias in the first SELECT in the UNION. The rest are required to use that column alias.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a reference table to store the list of `serial`s is probably your best option. That would allow you to write a query like:

```
SELECT r.serial reference_serial, s.serial system_serial
FROM reference_table r
LEFT JOIN system_table s ON s.serial = r.serial
```

With the `LEFT JOIN`, `serial`s declared in the reference table but unavailable in the system table will have second column set to `NULL`.

A quick and dirty work around is to use `UNION`ed subqueries to emulate the reference table:

```
SELECT r.serial reference_serial, s.serial system_serial
FROM (
    SELECT 'serial1' AS serial
    UNION ALL SELECT 'serial2'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'serial2'
    ...
) r
LEFT JOIN system_table s ON s.serial = r.serial
```